# Intermittent PowerShell "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" exception

Tags: powershell, exception, mutex

Very infrequently (less than 0.1% of function calls) I see an exception from inside a function. The function writes a log entry to a common log file and the intent is that it will wait until it can obtain the mutex that controls writing to the common file.

Relevant code snippet:

```
function WriteSummary ([string]$fnContent)  
{
    $fnTimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss.ff"
    Try {
        [void]$SummaryLogMutex.WaitOne()
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($script:SummaryLog,("$fnTimeStamp $fnContent") + ([Environment]::NewLine))
    } Catch {
        $FullException = ($_ | Format-List -Force | Out-String)
        WriteActivity -fnContent ("$FullException")
    } Finally {
        [void]$SummaryLogMutex.ReleaseMutex()
    }
}

$SummaryLogMutex = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "Global\SummaryLogMutex")

WriteSummary -fnContent ("Some text")
```

The exception is as follows:

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You 
                        cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps
                        .CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, 
                        Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCa
                        llInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTry
                        CatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTry
                        CatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

The trace indicates it is "[void]$SummaryLogMutex.WaitOne()" causing the exception.

I would be grateful for help with understanding and resolving what is going on.

*Modified code to be tested to create object inside try block and avoid invoking method on variable set to null:*

```
function WriteSummary ([string]$fnContent)  
{
    $fnTimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss.ff"
    Try {
        If (!$script:SummaryLogMutex) {
            $script:SummaryLogMutex = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "Global\SummaryLogMutex")
            WriteActivity -fnContent ("Created Summary Log Mutex")
        }
        [void]$script:SummaryLogMutex.WaitOne()
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($script:SummaryLog,("$fnTimeStamp $fnContent") + ([Environment]::NewLine))
    } Catch {
        $FullException = ($_ | Format-List -Force | Out-String)
        WriteActivity -fnContent ("$FullException")
    } Finally {
        [void]$script:SummaryLogMutex.ReleaseMutex()
    }
}

WriteSummary -fnContent ("Some text")
```

Comment: The implication is that `$SummaryLogMutex` contains `$null` (or is an undefined variable) when the method call is attempted. The code shown would _not_ explain why that happens, however.

Comment: How, and from where, are you calling `WriteSummary`? The sample you listed only calls it once, but your question text implies it's called many times

Comment: Script is several thousand lines and the function is called at various points. However  $SummaryLogMutex is referenced in only three places as shown in the snippet i.e. creation outside the function and twice in the function. I had not considered that $SummaryLogMutex might be null; the code would not catch that explicitly.

Comment: @AdrianWilson The recommended pattern would be to call `Mutex.OpenExisting($mutexName)` instead of relying on resolving the `$SummaryLogMutex` variable from the callers scope inside the function (which may be a pretty slow operation btw), but I'm still curious as to why it fails. Are you using any parallel execution features (`ForEach -Parallel`, runspace pooling, thread jobs, etc.)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The script does not do any parallel execution. Multiple instances of the script may run in parallel of course (hence the need for the mutex). The errors seem to occur in groups and once they start they increase in regularity. A server restart resolves the situation. The containing script moves files around and does some processing of the files as it does so. The intent is to be highly robust and performance is given little consideration. I will amend the script again with your suggested pattern; makes sense as an approach and I prefer it over my existing approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior (`$SummaryLogMutex` intermittently resolves to `$null` inside `WriteSummary` even though it exists in the callers scope), but I suspect you can avoid it entirely by using your *named* mutex differently.

Since it has a name, we can easily obtain a handle to it without relying on `$SummaryLogMutex`:

```
function WriteSummary ([string]$fnContent)  
{
    $fnTimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss.ff"
    Try {
        [void][System.Threading.Mutex]::OpenExisting("Global\SummaryLogMutex").WaitOne()
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($script:SummaryLog,("$fnTimeStamp $fnContent") + ([Environment]::NewLine))
    }
```

Now we can reliably catch failures:

```
catch [System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException] {
   # handle non-existing mutex (eg. create it)
}
```